# How to get TD cell values using jquery

Tags: jquery, html, html-table, html-tableextract

I would like to get the text from the first and second TD which has the class user and id

```
<tr class="item-model-number">
  <td class="label">Item model number</td>
  <td class="value">GL552VW-CN426T</td>
</tr>
```

I have tried this jQuery code but didn't work for me:

```
$(".item-model-number").find("td").each(function() {
  var test = $(this).text();
  alert(test);
}
```

I want to retrieve `GL552VW-CN426T` from inside the second `td` tag in the `tr`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just need to amend your selector to get the correct element:

```js
$(".item-model-number .value").each(function() {
  var value = $(this).text();
  console.log(value);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr class="item-model-number">
    <td class="label">Item model number</td>
    <td class="value">GL552VW-CN426T</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're always getting the second `td` tag that contains the value, you can just use the class selector to select the DOM element using `$('.item-model-number .value')`.

If you want to get the second `td` tag without using the class name on it, you can do an nth of type selector using `$('.item-model-number td:nth-of-type(2)')`.

To get the content of the DOM element, you can call `.text()` on the jQuery elements returned by the selector so the whole thing would look like `$('.item-model-number .value').text()` or `$('.item-model-number td:nth-of-type(2)').text()`